Delete Chart Data Labels with value zero from a selected chart
The following code allows the user to delete Chart Data Labels with a value of zero from a named chart.
To select a chart, the user has to enter the chart name in the macro.
In this example, the name is "Chart abc".
How do you build the code, so that the user can simply select a chart by clicking on it?
Sub DeleteZeroValueLabelsfromSelectedChart()
'  If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
'     MsgBox "No chart selected. Please select a chart."
'  Else
  Dim cht As Chart
  Dim chtObj As ChartObject  
  Set chtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart abc") 'SET
  Set cht = chtObj.Chart
    Dim ser As Series
    For Each ser In cht.SeriesCollection
        Dim vals As Variant
        vals = ser.Values
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
            If vals(i) = 0 Then
                With ser.Points(i)
                    If .HasDataLabel Then
                        .DataLabel.Delete
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        Next i
    Next ser
End Sub

How do you say:
  Set chtObj = ActiveChart


Set cht = ActiveChart

@BigBen: This causes an error: the line For Each ser In cht.SeriesCollection is highlighted yellow.

What's the specific error message?

"Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set"

Then ActiveChart is Nothing likely. Do you have the chart selected?

The code as is needs the user to input the chart name in the code, in this example it's ("Chart abc"). If you run the macro, the chart is automatically selected by its name. Trying to modify it to ask the user to select the chart by clicking on it.

If the user selects the chart before running the macro, then you can use ActiveChart.

Like this: "Delete TextBoxes from a selected chart" link

I must be missing something, because both answers in that link use ActiveChart, as I'm suggesting. Note that charts and chartobjects are not the same thing. If you want the chartobject specifically, then note that the accepted answer in that link uses Selection and TypeName to identify the chartobject.

One possibility using Set cht = ActiveChart:
Sub DeleteZeroValueLabelsfromSelectedChart_v1()
  If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
     MsgBox "No chart selected. Please select a chart."
  Else   
  Dim cht As Chart
'  Dim chtObj As ChartObject    
'  Set chtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart abc")   
'  Set cht = chtObj.Chart
  Set cht = ActiveChart
    Dim ser As Series
    For Each ser In cht.SeriesCollection
        Dim vals As Variant
        vals = ser.Values
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
            If vals(i) = 0 Then
                With ser.Points(i)
                    If .HasDataLabel Then
                        .DataLabel.Delete
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        Next i
    Next ser
  End If
End Sub


@BigBen: turning off the "chtObj"-lines did the trick.
